# Call method on object on which generic type is not known except at runtime? Should I just use a dynamic?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, generic-type-argument

say I have a class

```
public abstract class A<T>
{
     public T GetT{get;}

     public ISomeInterface AMethod{get;}
}
```

Then I have some other method in another class where I take an object and I want to check it is of type `A<>`  then if it is get the type of `T` and call the method `AMethod`.  So I'm doing this:

```
if (theObject.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (A<>))
{
    Type TType = theObject.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];            
    dynamic dynamicObject= theObject;
    ISomeInterface filter = dynamicObject.AMethod;
    //...some other stuff using TType
}
```

Is there a way to do this without using the dynamic object, since I can't declare the type of the variable using the `TType` or using the generic type defintion `A<>` at runtime...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're able to, put all the non-generic stuff in an abstract non-generic base class:

```
public abstract class A
{
     public ISomeInterface AMethod{get;}
}

public abstract class A<T> : A
{
     public T GetT{get;}
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
A foo = theObject as A;
if (foo != null)
{
    ISomeInterface filter = foo.AMethod;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I'm not able to pull things into a non generic base class then using the `dynamic` is as good as I'm going to get?

Comment: Well you could use some explicit reflection to pull out and invoke the property getter; but it would be arguable whether that's better/worse.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Mr. Skeet, pulling items which don't depend on the class type into a non-generic class or interface is generally the way to go when practical.  Otherwise, I would suggest writing a generic method with type parameter `T` which will return a generic singleton (generated via Reflection) that can pass an object to a generic method with parameter types `U` such that `T:A<U>`.  Such a method would only have to use Reflection once for any particular type `T`, no matter how many times it was used to handle instances of that type.

Because delegates are only usable with closed generics, one would probably have to define some generic interfaces:

```
// User code will supply an implementation of one of these interfaces to the dispatching
// object, which will call its "Act" method with a proper type
interface IActUponGenericA
{
  void Act<T>(A<T> param);
}
interface IActUponGenericA<PT1>
{
  void Act<T>(A<T> param, PT1 extraParam1);
}
interface IActUponGenericA<PT1,PT2>
{
  void Act<T>(A<T> param, PT1 extraParam1, PT2 extraParam2);
}
// The dispatching object itself will implement this interface:
interface IWrapActUponGenericA<T>
{
  void CallAction(IActUponGenericA act, T param);
  void CallAction<PT1>(IActUponGenericA<PT1> act, T param, PT1 extraParam1);
  void CallAction<PT1,PT2>(IActUponGenericA<PT1,PT2> act, T param, 
                             PT1 extraParam1, PT2 extraParam2);
}
```

Then given a parameter type `T` (which implements `A<Q>` for some `Q`), the Reflection-based method code will generate a singleton which implements interface `IWrapActUponGenericA<T>`.  That implementation can take an object of type `T`, and an implementation of `IActUponGenericA`, and call that implementation's `Act<Q>` method.

This approach will be more complicated than using `dynamic`, and may or may not perform better; it will, however, be able to deal with some situations that `dynamic` can't.